# NO signal as Windows XP starts while Running absoultly well with Window 98

Tags: windows, windows-xp, external-display

### Introduction

I have been using a PC with a P3 processor (Intel 810E) with 256 MB SD RAM for the last 8 years. I have 2 operating systems on my PC for the last 3-4 years. Windows 98 and Windows XP.

I have two hard disks with a capacity of 20GB and 80GB. Both operating systems have been installed on separate hard disks.

I've been using an LCD 22" TV as a monitor for the last 4 months.

### Problem

Since the last 5 days, I am facing a problem when I boot into Windows XP. The monitor goes blank and gives a `NO SIGNAL` error while the CPU is running. Then I try to restart it again and again, some of the times the monitor gets the signal and running well and sometimes not.

The strange thing is that when I boot Windows 98, it is working fine. There is no problem, the monitor is working fine.

In an attempt to solve the issue, I have already formatted the drive on which Windows XP was installed and again reinstalled Windows XP with different installation CDs 4-5 times.

But the problem remains as it is.

I have also installed Windows XP on the other hard disk on which Windows 98 is installed. But that had no effect on the problem.

Answer (score 3):

If the screen is going blank and displays "no signal", most often one of these two things are misconfigured:

- Screen resolution
- Screen refresh rate (frequency)

It is uncommon, but could be happen if you update your display driver.

To check this, you could start in recovery mode by pressing F8 on startup, which will use a low resolution. If this works, you can go on from there.

Comment: my bet is on the drivers as well, either the ones that XP loads for the monitor/TV or for the graphics adapter.

Answer (score 0):

This is rather old hardware.  It may be beginning to go out, especially if your area is prone to power fluctuations and you've had the system connected directly to the wall for years.

You may try replacing the graphics card.

This would be especially likely if you are using 640x480 resolution in Windows 98, but your screen becomes invisible after Windows XP tries to change the resolution to 800x600 for the first time.